# Use NIB UIView as subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use a `UIView` from a XIB to display in a sub view container in another view
controller. This is how I try to do display the subView in in MainViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *subView;
```

MainViewController.m:

```
UIViewController* nameController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NamesViewController" bundle:nil];
subView = [nameController view];

[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

But I get this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x688e580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textField.'`

Is there something I am doing wrong or have I missed something?
I made a the NamesViewController class with xib, put a textfield in the view, now trying to use the view from this xib as subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be allocating `NamesViewController` rather than a "plain" `UIViewController`:

```
UIViewController* nameController = [[NamesViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"NamesViewController"
             bundle:nil];
```

Otherwise, any attempt to connect `IBOutlet`s would result in a crash. Of course I'm only assuming that the NIB name matches the controller's name; if it does not, you need to use the correct name.